# Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' date toIso8601String Flutter

Tags: flutter

```
required this.paymentDate,
```

`final DateTime paymentDate;`

`paymentDate: DateTime.parse(json["payment_date"])`

```
"payment_date": paymentDate.toIso8601String()
```

Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' date toIso8601String Flutter

Answer (score 0):

This is because your variable `paymentDate` is null: It was not initialized with a valid value.

Double-check your "`payment_date`" in `json`: you most likely have a typo in the name of variable (case sensitive), or the date is not valid date.

Comment: Let me know if this does not help